# Нужно ли использовать begin чтобы сработало else?

Tags: pascal

Как правильно оформить условие? Можно ли сделать так:

```
if (x <> 1001) then
  writeln(x)
else 
  writeln('-1');
```

Или нужно делать так:

```
if (x <> 1001) then begin
  writeln(x);
end
else 
  writeln('-1');
```

Нужно ли писать `begin`, чтобы сработало `else` (как во 2 случае)? Или `else` может работать и без `begin`? (как в первом случае)

Comment: вы бы за время пока этот вопрос набирали и форматировали могли бы раз 10 проверить это на практике.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если действие после `then` одно, то можно и без `begin .. end` его записать.

---

`begin .. end` в условиях, обычно используется для предотвращения ошибок в логике и формирования правильной структуры нескольких условий. Например:

```delphi
// Неправильное форматирование и структуру не так просто заметить
if (x <> 1001) then
  writeln(x);
  if x <> 1002 then
    writeln(x)
else 
  writeln('-1');  // этот else относится ко второму if, а не к первому!

// А вот так, все наглядно
if (x <> 1001) then
begin
  writeln(x);
  if x <> 1002 then
    writeln(x)
end
else 
  writeln('-1');
```

Answer (score 4):

Да, можно так написать это не считается неправильным

Обычно блок

```
Begin
...
End
```

используют для объединения нескольких команд в единый блок, но нет запрета на использования блока для одной команды как в вашем случае. Но есть рекомендации использовать `begin end` нежели опускать, по причине если в дальнейшей разработки вы добавите еще одну команду то в `else` есть вероятность что вы можете упустить добавить блок и ваша новая команда будет выполняться всегда.

```
else
 firstcommand();

....

else
 onecommand();
 secondcommand();
```

или

```
else
 begin
  firstcommand();
 end
....

else
 begin
  onecommand();
  secondcommand();
 end;
```